# GTA 5 autosaving issue

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

First of all, thanks in advance for another help. This time I have been facing a problem with autosave function in GTA 5. My issue is that whenever I open the game, it starts from just before *Fame or Shame* mission where Trevor is standing at his safehouse (let's call this *point A* in the storyline). After that, I complete 4-5 missions, say, reaching *point B*. But once I open the game again, it starts back from *point A*. The autosave feature doesn't seem to have saved my progress towards *point B*. And it is happening again and again. My autosave is on and I also reinstalled the game, but that didn't fix the problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: On which platform are you playing?

Answer (score -1):

If you have used any cheats, it could turn the autosave feature off. If this were me, I would use the quicksave feature on the in-game phone then delete all other saves and restart my game.